# Backup From Windows Server 2012 R2 (Essentials) to NAS (Synology or Qnap)

Tags: windows, nas, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm new here.

I saw that many of you had the same issue. You can not make a back-up of your Windows server 2012r2 over the network to a NAS.

So, I hope someone fixed the problem.
I just need to make back-up only at some files from the server.
I will use (for server):

2xSSD 150G each (RAID 1 - to have a back-up system)
2xHDD 2T.each. Of course, will be RAID1 also.
Well, i still need back-up to a NAS only for those 2 HDD (so not for the entire System). Practically, i need only some folder to be copied to NAS.

Which is the best solution? Because i dont want to buy a NAS if will not work.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

If you only need some folders to be copied, I suggest you to create a script using robocopy managing the options you want and need. 
robocopy C:\temp N:\temp /mir would mirror the folder.